# What is the meaning of the % operator?

Tags: perl

I saw recently in on an answer here on Stackoverflow where a calculation was done to determine whether a value was odd or even. There was a `%` used which always returned 0 or 1 depending on the value it was compared with.

I am trying to figure out what the usage is of this `%` and even though I searched on google, I could only find `%` used in hash.

```
$result = $str % 2;
```

Comment: I don't understand your reference to the error `% not hash reference`. The code you show doesn't produce `Not a HASH reference`, which is presumably what you're referring to.

Comment: @Borodin: I think the "reference" in the title is a mistake. I think the title should be read as "What is the meaning of % in Perl when it's not used as a hash sigil?" I could be wrong.

Comment: @Borodin apologies. I meant _what is the meaning of % other than being used in hash_ and I fixed it now, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the "modulo" operator, see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop).

> [...] computes the division remainder of its first argument with respect to its second argument.

Answer (score 8):

The modulus operator gives you the remainder from an integer division.

You saw it being used to work out if a number is odd or even. When you divide an integer by 2, you get a remainder of 0 (if the number is even) or 1 (if the number is odd).

```
my $is_odd = $num % 2;
```

In general, the modulus will give you an integer between 0 and one less than the right-hand operand in the expression.

Like all operators, it is documented in [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), which says:

> Binary `"%"` is the modulo operator, which computes the division remainder of its first argument with respect to its second argument. Given integer operands `$m` and `$n` : If `$n` is positive, then `$m % $n` is `$m` minus the largest multiple of `$n` less than or equal to `$m`. If `$n` is negative, then `$m % $n` is `$m` minus the smallest multiple of `$n` that is not less than `$m` (that is, the result will be less than or equal to zero). If the operands `$m` and `$n` are floating point values and the absolute value of `$n` (that is `abs($n)`) is less than `(UV_MAX + 1)`, only the integer portion of `$m` and `$n` will be used in the operation (Note: here `UV_MAX` means the maximum of the unsigned integer type). If the absolute value of the right operand (`abs($n)`) is greater than or equal to `(UV_MAX + 1)` , `"%"` computes the floating-point remainder `$r` in the equation `($r = $m - $i*$n)` where `$i` is a certain integer that makes `$r` have the same sign as the right operand `$n` (**not** as the left operand `$m` like C function `fmod()`) and the absolute value less than that of `$n`. Note that when `use integer` is in scope, `"%"` gives you direct access to the modulo operator as implemented by your C compiler. This operator is not as well defined for negative operands, but it will execute faster.

Answer (score 7):

This `%` is a modulus operator which returns the remainder of the left operand divided by the right operand, which is zero in the case where the value on the left is divisible by the value on the right. It does not represents a hash sigil if it is between two operands.

See [*Perl & modulus* on perlmonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=431076) .

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the others, `%` is the [**modulo operator**](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.4/perlop#Multiplicative-Operators), and it returns the remainder after doing arithmetic division.  It's rather common to want the remainder (the results of the modulus) ***and*** the quotient (the results of the division).  Fortunately, it's very easy to get both in Perl!

I will take a working, mathematical form as: `dividend / divisor = quotient + remainder`.

[image]

You can always get the quotient and remainder by means of...

```
my $dividend = 100;
my $divisor = 3;
my ($quotient, $remainder) = (int $dividend / $divisor, $dividend % $divisor);
print($dividend . ' / ' . $divisor . ' = ' . $quotient . ' (quotient) + ' . $remainder . ' (remainder)');
```

And this gives the results:

> `100 / 3 = 33 (quotient) + 1 (remainder)`

This is a nice, useful one-line solution.  Here's a practical demonstration of it with a time example...

```
my $diff = 642;
my $divisor = 60;
my ($minutes, $seconds) = (int $diff / $divisor, $diff % $divisor);
print($minutes . ':' . $seconds);
```